# How can I determine if a job offer I received from a company in the UAE is genuine or a scam?

Tags: human-resources, scam

I recently got a job offer from a company named OCAM OIL AND GAS COMPANY, ABU DHABI, UAE. I want to know if this company is genuine.

I searched about the company on Google but I couldn't find enough about the company. They have also asked for money for the work permit and visa and the money had to be paid to RikAir tours and travels in Abu Dhabi.

I am reluctant to pay as I doubt their credibility. Can anyone please help?  It also has a stamp from Ministry of Interior, UAE.

Comment: Do not hand over any money

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Th success of a scam is predicated by the marks not being able to see what you have stated.

Comment: No legitimate job offer will ask you to send money for anything.

Comment: In the highly unlikely case that fees would have to be paid, the company would either cover the fees, or take them out of your first salary. Like a genuine foreign lottery where you won a million and then they need 1000 in processing fees would just send you 999,000.

Answer (score 24):

This is a scam.  The UAE has [this website](https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/tips-to-avoid-labour-and-visa-fraud) devoted to helping identify scams and visa fraud.

Among the items of that site:

> If somebody offers you a job in the UAE, he/she has to give you an
> offer letter issued by the UAE’s Ministry of Human Resources and
> Emiratisation (MOHRE).
>
> The prospective employees/candidates can verify the job offer’s
> validity at the UAE embassy in their country. You can use the job
> offer number to verify employer’s validity at the MOHRE’s website
> ([enquiry service - application status](https://www.mohre.gov.ae/en/services/enquiry-services.aspx)).

And

> Make sure that the company legally exists. You can search the
> company’s English and Arabic name in the [National Economic
> register](https://ner.economy.ae) and get company details.

That would be good starting point to validate the company.  There are also lots of other resources on the internet when you search for "Abu Dhabi visa scam"

[This site](https://legaladviceme.com/legal-blog/138/scam-alert-fake-uae-job-offers) says (in part)

> 1. The fraudsters allegedly post jobs online with too good to be true
>    salaries and unbelievable benefits.
> 2. Then without interview provide an offer letter which includes the
>    names and logos of the employer with or without fake UAE Embassy
>    stamp.
> 3. The fake job offer will provide a mobile number (starting from
>    009715 5 or 009715 0) and not a landline (009714 ) and a fake UAE
>    Embassy stamp which is not done in the UAE. Every company must have a
>    landline starting from 009714.
> 4. Then you will receive an offer letter asking you to pay the visa
>    processing fee - This is not a process followed here. The employer and
>    a travel agency cannot be connected.

Answer (score 12):

This is just the well-known "Total scam" or "Oil visa scam"  https://www.total.uk/fraudulent-job-offers-name-total

(They just use the name of any old major oil company .. Exxon, whatever.)

It's the most well-known scam in the middle-east, India, etc and it's the most well-known visa scam.

For goodness sake, **IT'S A SCAM.**